# Drupal splashify module making page fully white

Tags: php, drupal

I am using splashify module (for customized front page) in drupal. After accessing the website content and then finally clicking the home menu button in drupal website, the page gets white. Then again pressing enter key the home page of the website is displayed. If I disabled splashify module, website working normally.

Can any one suggested me how to rectify this problem?

this is the website url : www.kodikunnilsuresh.in

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting language, it does not have anything to do with keyboard events. What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is not much info in your question also throw in some code snippet if possible.

Comment: i am using splashify module (for customized front page) in drupal. after accessing the website content and then finally clicking the home menu button in drupal website going white screen display. then again pressing enter key only displaying the home page of the website. can any one suggested me how to rectify this problem. if i am not using splashify module, website working normally. please help

Comment: i have check the recent log messages in drupal there is no error in that list. but once i have remove the splashify module its working fine. otherwise its displaying white screen and i have used in this line ini_set("display_errors", 1); in index.php file but its not showing any error

Comment: so if u would give any idea to trigger enter key event automatically while index page loading. it will helpful for me because after white page comes once i have press enter key in key board the index page open properly so

Comment: I have re-writted your question to show the real problem. I hope you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd debug this:

First, when the screen is white, view the source.  Is there HTML, or is the page empty?

You can see this in chrome with Ctrl-Shift-C, or in Firefox with Firebug.

a) If the page is empty (e.g. , then the module is causing a WSOD.
https://drupal.org/node/158043

If this is the case, the module has a bug in it, and you should file an issue.

b) If the page has content (e.g. you see your HTML), then you are probably seeing an overlay.  Splashify does a lightbox thing, and it's likely the lightbox has no content.

If this is the case, the module may not be configured correctly.  Check the documentation for details.

Good luck!

Mike

Comment: the page has content but i have configured the module correctly but the same problem repeats. what should i do?

Comment: Hey Bala, did my answer help?  If so, select it!  Did you try a) and b) above.  What happened?

Comment: Hey Bala, ok great.  I'd check for the splashify content it was configured with - it may be hidden for some reason.  If that doesn't work, change the splashify content to something simple like "Hello World".  If that doesn't work, you may need to put a debugger on it.

Comment: Yes i have checked by displaying only "Welcome" word and plus link to enter website . but splashily module not working properly. it is displaying only blank screen. kindly help me please